# Xpath or Css selector to find value of maxlength attribute

Tags: python, selenium

I want to extract value of maxlength attr using xpath or css selector from following html

```
<div class="qty-box" data-reactid=".8.0.0"><input class="qty-box-input" 
   id="qtyMainItems" title="quantity box" type="text" value="1" 
     maxlength="3" data-reactid=".8.0.0.0" style=""><button type="button"
```

please guide me. here is the css selector im trying so far -

```
"#qtyMainItems  .maxlength").value()
```

Comment: I don't know Python but there is not class `.maxlength` in your xml, this is an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this for xpath

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="qtyMainItems"]')
element.get_attribute('maxlength')
```

If it's not a very complex structure though you might not need to worry about xpath at all. Instead you could just explicity search for the elements with a given id like so:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('qtyMainItems')
element.get_attribute('maxlength')
```

Comment: Thanks..This is indeed i was looking for